# Кто такой активист? Каково значение этого слова и его происхождение?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, заимствования, значение

В последнее время как из отечественных средств массовой информации, так и из зарубежных можно часто услышать про активистов.

При этом очень широкий круг занятий рассматривается, как область деятельности активистов. Кого только активистами не называют.

Но кто же они всё-таки такие? Что понятие «активист» под собой подразумевает в русском языке? И как оно возникло?

Слово явно иностранного происхождения. Когда-то оно было заимствовано в русский язык. Но в какую эпоху, в связи с какими событиями и из какого языка было заимствовано не известно.
Единственный словарь, в котором я нашёл информацию по этимологии — это Викисловарь; в доступных мне этимологических словарях информации об этом нет. Но об этимологии позже.

Можно было бы подумать, что это слово новое. Но нет. Оно не ново и при этом прочно удерживает свои позиции не зависимо от политического строя.

Словари дают сходные значения:

> Егеньева 
> АКТИВИ́СТ, -а, м. Деятельный член какого-л. коллектива; общественник.
>
> Большой толковый словарь дублирует Егеньеву:
> АКТИВИСТ, -а; м.
> Активный, деятельный представитель какого-л. коллектива, организации;
> общественник.
>
> Ушаков:
> АКТИВИ'СТ, а, м. (полит. нов.). Лицо, принадлежащее к активу
> (в 1 знач.). При этом АКТИ́В 1, -а, м. Наиболее деятельная часть
> какой-л. организации, коллектива.
>
> Ефремова:
> АКТИВИСТ м. Деятельный член какой-л. организации, какого-л.
> коллектива; тот, кто принадлежит к активу (1*). При этом АКТИВ 1)
> Наиболее деятельная группа лиц какой-л. общественной организации,
> какого-л. коллектива.
>
> Ожегов
> АКТИВИ́СТ, -а, м. Тот, кто принадлежит к активу 1, деятельный
> член какого-нибудь коллектива. || ж. активи́стка, -и. || прил.
> активи́стский, -ая, -ое. При этом АКТИ́В 1, -а, м. Наиболее
> деятельная часть какой-л. организации, коллектива.

Таким образом словари в основном сходятся во мнении, что активист, это член актива, а актив это наиболее деятельная часть какой-либо организации, коллектива.

Но это совершенно не вяжется с тем, как люди используют слово «активист». Получается, что наиболее деятельных работников завода можно назвать активистами.

Но в новостях явно не говорится про наиболее деятельных сотрудников почты, железной дороги, учебного заведения, шахтёров и т. п.

Справедливости ради надо сказать, что в словаре Евгеньевой есть после точки с запятой слово «общественник». Однако согласно тому, что написано в начале этого словаря: после точки с запятой идут синонимы. Таким образом, определение до точки с запятой, а общественник к определению не относится.

Но можно посмотреть, кто такой общественник в этом же словаре:

> ОБЩЕ́СТВЕННИК, -а, м. 1. Тот, кто активно участвует в общественной
> жизни. *[Орлов] прикреплен был к избирательному участку в глухих горах.
> Человек словоохотливый, он был общественником по натуре.* Павленко,
> Идут дожди. 2. Устар. Крестьянин, член общества (в 5 знач.). *Отец был
> родом из этого завода и по паспорту числился крестьянином Полевской
> волости и завода. Там он, как полевской общественник, имел право на
> покосный надел.* Бажов, У старого рудника.

Большой толковый словарь, по-видимому, взял толкование из Евгеньевой и в месте с ним слово «общественник», поэтому посмотрим и в нём:

> ОБЩЕСТВЕННИК, -а; м. Человек, который активно участвует в общественной
> жизни, работе; человек, выполняющий какие-л. обязанности на
> общественных началах. Я по натуре своей о. Работа общественника - дело
> неблагодарное, не сулящее выгод...

Общественник тоже размытое понятие. Что именно делает человек, который активно участвует в общественной жизни? На субботники ходит? Или это какой-то «массовик-затейник» в коллективе? А выполнять обязанности на общественных началах — это работать бесплатно. Так это волонтёр?

Интересное использование слова «общественник» у Льва Толстого в романе Воскресенье:

> «Впереди шли солдаты, за ними, бренча цепями, кандальные, по четыре в
> ряд, зa ними ссыльные, потом общественники, скованные руками по-двое
> наручнями, потом женщины».

Ну если общественников отправили на каторгу, то может это таки аналог современных активистов? Не понятно.

Теперь о происхождении:

Ушаков в своём словаре пометил слово как политическое и новое. Его словарь издан в 1935—1940. Значит слово возникло примерно в то время.
По его мнению, активист — это член актива, а актив происходит от  лат. activus — деятельный.
Такого же мнения Ожегов.

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82) утверждает со ссылкой на Краткий этимологический словарь русского языка Бархударова:

> Суффиксное производное от русск. актив, далее от activus
> «действующий», далее из actus «действие» из agere «приводить в
> движение, гнать» (восходит к праиндоевр. *ag- «гнать, двигать»).
> Возникло в 30-е годы XX в.

Та же история. Активист член актива, актив — деятельные люди в организации, коллективе. Происхождение актива от activus «действующий».

Но это вызывает большое удивление. Даже относительно современные словари: Большой толковый и Ефремовой утверждаю, что активист — это просто активный член организации, коллектива. Ну или ещё какой-то непонятный общественник, но у Ефремовой про общественника ничего не сказано, а Большой толковый, судя по всему, взял «общественника» из Евгеньевой, у которой это не определение, а синоним.

Если обратится [Оксфордскому словарю английского языка](https://www.lexico.com/definition/activist):

> Activist — A person who campaigns to bring about political or social
> change.
> ‘police arrested three activists’
>
> Активист — человек, который осуществляет мероприятия, чтобы добиться
> политических или общественных изменений.
> *«Полиция арестовала трёх активистов».*

Но это уже ближе к истине.

Трудно перевести точно, но суть понятна. Так получается в русскоязычных средствах массой информации используется английское, а не русское определение слова?

Если обратится за этимологией в [английский этимологический словарь](https://www.etymonline.com/word/activist):

> activist (n.) "one who advocates a doctrine of direct action" in any
> sense, 1915; from active + -ist. Originally in reference to a
> political movement in Sweden advocating abandonment of neutrality in
> World War I and active support for the Central Powers. The word was
> used earlier in philosophy (1907).
>
> активист (сущ.) «тот, кто являться сторонником доктрины прямого
> действия» в любом смысле, 1915; из active + -ist. Первоначально в
> отношении политического движения в Швеции, выступающего за отказ от
> нейтралитета в Первой мировой войне и активную поддержку Центральных
> держав. Слово использовалось ранее в философии (1907 г.).

Кто-то знает, как это слово использовалось ранее в философии?

Получается активсит происходит от direct **action** (прямое действие). В начале говорится, что активист — это тот, кто являться сторонником доктрины прямого действия.
Это похоже на то, как слово используется в русском языке.

Что это может значить? Я понимаю так, что действовать можно по принятым правилам, соблюдая иерархию власти, а можно напрямую обращаться к самому верху. Например, если человеку не платят зарплату, он может обратиться в профсоюз, подать в суд на работодателя и т. п. Это будет непрямое действие. Он действует, через других людей. А прямое — это пойти сразу к верховным властям и устроить там протест. Или, если во дворе дома началась стройка, которая закрое свет, то непрямое действие — это писать жалобы чиновникам (действовать через них), а прямое пойти и всё поломать (самим).

Прямое действие в англоязычной [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_action):

> Direct action originated as a political activist term for economic and
> political acts in which the actors use their power (e.g. economic or
> physical) to directly reach certain goals of interest; in contrast to
> those actions that appeal to others (e.g. authorities); by, for
> example, revealing an existing problem, using physical violence,
> highlighting an alternative, or demonstrating a possible solution.
>
> Both direct action and actions appealing to others can include
> nonviolent and violent activities which target persons, groups, or
> property deemed offensive to the action participants. Nonviolent
> direct action may include sit-ins, strikes, street blockades,
> sabotage, and counter-economics. Violent direct action may include
> political violence, assault, arson and property destruction.
>
> Прямое действие возникло как политический активистский термин для
> обозначения экономических и политических действий, в которых субъекты
> используют свою силу (например, экономическую или физическую) для
> непосредственного достижения определённых целей, представляющих
> интерес; в отличие от действий, которые обращаются к другим [людям] (например, к
> властям); путём, например, выявления существующей проблемы, применения
> физического насилия, подчёркивания альтернативы или демонстрации
> возможного решения.
>
> Как прямые действия, так и действия, обращённые к другим [людям], могут
> включать ненасильственные и насильственные действия, направленные на
> людей, группы или имущество, которые считаются обидный для участников
> действия. Ненасильственные прямые действия могут включать сидячие
> забастовки, забастовки, уличные блокады, саботаж и меры
> противодействия экономике. Прямые насильственные действия могут
> включать политическое насилие, нападение, поджог и уничтожение
> имущества.

Что из этого следует.
Получается, что «активист» — это тот кто действует напрямую. Действовать не напрямую — действовать посредством других. Например, избрать депутатов или президента, которые будут представлять твои интересы во власти. Действовать напрямую — это идти и чего требовать у тех, от кого это напрямую зависит. Или, например, если что-то мешает просто пойти и поломать, а не добиваться законными механизмами, чтоб это убрали.

Но это мнение основано на англоязычных источниках.

Дайте, пожалуйста, ответы:

1. Каково современное значение слова активист? Соответствует ли оно тому,
   что в словарях русского языка?
2. Назвалось ли то, что сейчас называется «активистом», раньше «общественником». Почему у Льва Толстого общественники на каторге.
3. Какова этимология слова «активист»? Это всё-таки член актива или человек, которой действует напрямую, или есть ещё какое-то объяснение?
4. Почему слово «активист» стало использоваться в русском языке в 1930-х годах, что тогда происходило, что была необходимость заимствования этого слова. Было ли слово «активист» до 1930-х в русском языке? Может было, но его переиначили неправильно.
5. Какое могло быть философское использование слова активист в 1907 г.? (Это немного не по теме раздела, потому что факт из английского словаря, но философия — она международная наука, если использовалось у них, то могло использоваться и у нас. Может это прольёт свет на происхождение слова.)

Comment: https://te-st.ru/2020/09/22/what-is-activism/

Comment: @V.V. Спасибо за статью. Написано сложно и похоже написано, чтоб написать статью. Но информацию почерпнуть можно. Есть в конце определение; есть об этимологии, хотя по этимологии хотелось бы больше конкретики.